# Migrate Kettle from 3.2 to 4.1

Tags: pentaho, kettle

Is there any documentation/tutorial on how to migrate Kettle in an application (for executing transformations, not for creating them) from version 3.2 to the current 4.1? I could not find any useful ressource on the web, so any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you executing the job / transformation from repository ? If not - you are using .ktr / .kjb file then you don't need to worry on upgrading.

Regards,

Dino

Comment: Those are .krt files, but I was more worried or troubled by the execution side: We use the kettle libraries in our own code, aka using the Java API. And that one seems to have changed quite a bit from 3.2 to 4.1 - but there is no migration guide.

Comment: have you checked the wiki - there is usually an API upgrade guide there - there was for 2.x -> 3.x

Comment: Hi DaDaDom, I suggest you to check out the Kettle source code and have a look at the Test Case. Usually it is the best place to learn and look for difference of the API behaviors.

Comment: @Codek: Sadly, no guide for 3.x->4.x in the Wiki.

Comment: @Dino: Thanks, that really seems to be the only option - but it means that I have to walk through the 3.x AND the 4.x code as I have to find out which lines in our code produce what result. E.g. initialization seems to be a one-liner now, having been a multi-liner before.

Comment: @DaDaDom: You're welcome. Currently the test cases itself is the best "documentation" available for me :)